# Laravel, phpunit bootstrap and doctrine create schema commands

Tags: symfony, laravel, doctrine-orm, phpunit

I'm creating a laravel package.
In this package I have several unit tests.
I create database tests too, that interacts with an actual test mysql database. I use doctrine as ORM tool.

Now I want when phpunit bootstraps, the doctrine command schema-tool:create and/or drop (in the end) must be called.
I call autoload_php as bootstrap file in phpunit.xml

I cannot find a way to create an App (with AppKernel) that can calls commands for doctrine.
Artisan is not available, as my package live in a packages folder in another laravel app. I've tried copying the functionality of artisan to my package folder, but I bump into many exceptions.

I found a description where you can bootstrap phpunit with a symfony application.
http://php-and-symfony.matthiasnoback.nl/2011/10/symfony2-use-a-bootstrap-file-for-your-phpunit-tests-and-run-some-console-commands/
But I wonder if there's more a laravel way to do this?

So in short:
how can I call doctrine commands when bootstrapping my phpunit tests.